# When To Make a Site As SPA

Tags: ajax, single-page-application

I will just provide a hypothetical case to understand the point. Let's assume I am creating a mailing application. If I refresh the data every time the user returns to the main mail list page from viewing a particular mail, is there an advantage to make this navigation on the client side via AJAX? Or does it make more sense to actually navigate to a new url for viewving a particular mail and a separate url for the main page?

The same question applies to other cases such as a shopping website. What are the advantages/disadvantages of making each product page a separate url rather than navigating to that product using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

With a one page app the navigation after the page load is quicker, and you can add effects for the page change, but if you have a lot of items to show, you should load data about it also, so the other approach should be better.